# Prettier way to write this query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, mongoose, database

hi is there a nicer / prettier way to write this query?

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
if (req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') == 1) {
    Timesheet.find()
        .sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, timesheets) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(timesheets);
            }
        });
}
else {


Timesheet.find()
    .where('user').equals(req.user.id)
    .sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, timesheets) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(timesheets);
        }
        });
}
};
```

only different is, if admin then add .where('user').equals(req.user.id)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Andy I was thinking the same, but I think it's Mongoose-specific enough to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the duplicate code you can refactor the code to just alter the way the query is built based on whether the user is in the admin role:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    var query = Timesheet.find();
    if (req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') !== 1) {
        query = query.where('user').equals(req.user.id);
    }
    query.sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, timesheets) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(timesheets);
        }
    });
}
```